# Xamarin: unsupported grant_type

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-web-app-service

I am building a cross-platform app via Xamarin framework. I have setup a back-end web API server which runs on localhost and as well as I have published it on Azure Web Services (myappname.azurewebsites.net). My problem is, I can get token from localhost by using Postman but I get an "unsupported grant_type" error if I try on Azure Web URL. Could anyone please help me with this? Do I need to change some settings on Azure Dashboard?

Screenshots:

Localhost:
[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpaCR.png)

Azure Web URL:
[Azure Web URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA8vW.png)

Comment: It is not the same problem on the other post that I am having.

Comment: You can ask to have the post reopened.  But there is nothing in your question that shows you have done ANYTHING to solve this yourself.  There are dozens of questions on SO already addressing this specific error message.  Please take the time to read them before you decide that your situation is unique.